# VBA Compiles in Word 2016 but not Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

One of the new features that MS have introduced to MS Word since Word 2010 is LayoutColumns FootnoteOptions.

So the following line of code compiles in Word 2016:   `ActiveDocument.Range.FootnoteOptions.LayoutColumns` but not in Word 2010 *(I've not tested in Word 2013)*.

The conditional compiler statements don't seem to help... there is nothing for application version except VBA7 which includes Word 2010.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/compiler-constants

So this won't compile in Word 2010:

```
Sub testWd10()
#If Win64 And VBA7 Then
    ActiveDocument.Range.FootnoteOptions.LayoutColumns
#End If
End Sub
```

[image: Compiler error - Method or data member not found]

Comment: seems to be "Office 2013 and later" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.footnoteoptions.layoutcolumns.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler directives won't help you. You need to determine the version, and use late-binding for the member calls that aren't in older versions of Word.

```
Sub testWd10()
  If Application.Version > 15 Then 'e.g. 15 is Word 2013, change as necessary
      Dim myRange As Object 'As Range
      Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
      myRange.FootnoteOptions.LayoutColumns 'Late-bound call
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah... that's better than what I just nutted out

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late, but few more late binding alternatives:

```
Dim o As Object
Set o = ActiveDocument.Range.FootnoteOptions
On Error Resume Next
o.LayoutColumns = 3
On Error GoTo 0
```

A bit shorter and slower:

```
On Error Resume Next
CallByName ActiveDocument.Range.FootnoteOptions, "LayoutColumns", vbSet, 3
On Error GoTo 0
```

or:

```
On Error Resume Next
CVar(ActiveDocument.Range.FootnoteOptions).LayoutColumns = 3
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Cool, thanks will have a look at those too - good to have options!

Comment: What is this `CObj` of which you speak? `VBA.CVar(ActiveDocument.Range.FootnoteOptions).LayoutColumns = 3` works in 2013.

Comment: Thanks @ThunderFrame. Wasn't sure if VBA has `CObj` as VB.Net, and this page seemed to suggest that it does http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/functions/builtin.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as ThunderFrame's answer because I think it is probably more efficient to set a range as an object than the whole application, but here goes:

```
Sub testWd10()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Set wdApp = Application

    If wdApp.Version > 14 Then
        wdApp.Documents(ActiveDocument.FullName).Range.FootnoteOptions.LayoutColumns
    End If
End Sub
```